Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Failed executing DbCommand, why?
We are getting visibility on SQL statements that error and are being sent to teams for visibility via our teams nlog target.
But there is nothing wrong with the SQL statements... so wondering why they might be failing from time to time?

ERROR - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Failed executing DbCommand (18,978ms)

Then we look in azure SQL for locks etc and nothing there? No where near the timeout setting of 30 seconds... sometimes we get an error for other queries with a way short time frame in the logs.
Here is our nlog rule below:
{
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "maxLevel": "Fatal",
        "writeTo": "teamsError",
        "final": true
}

What is the root cause? Should our nlog rule not be asterisk?

Good call @DaleK done :)

As you've noticed the Message on the wrapped exception is generic to the point of being useless. If you're using ${exception:format=message} have you considered using ${exception:format=toString} instead to capture the details of the inner exception (which should include SQL Server's ErrorNumber, State and Class values along with the original error message)?

Hey @AlwaysLearning we aren't using formatting

Could this be a database lock timeout? But yeah, you need to log the actual error, then you'll know.

Where/how are you logging database errors? If you have your own catch block, then you should use ILogger.BeginScope to add additional context to the logged error (assuming that NLog supports this - I don't know if NLog does), such as the raw SQL query (if you can get it out of EF) and the full InnerException chain.

I see you have bountied this question. But I don't think you are providing enough information for anyone to provide an answer. You certainly don't provide enough information to determine what the error is. Maybe your question is how to find out what the actual error is? But its not clear if so.

Your dealing with these random DbCommand timeouts, and despite your SQL working fine, they keep showing up every few days.
Could be brief network instability. Even though the cloud generally handles connections well, short-lived network blips can cause timeouts. These can be especially weird since they don't happen consistently and can be hard to catch in action.
Another factor could be Azure SQL's internal resource management. Even if you’re not hitting obvious limits like DTUs or eDTUs, temporary resource contention can still occur, causing queries to fail sporadically. Azure might throttle resources momentarily, leading to these errors, especially if there’s a brief spike in demand.
Your logging setup is key. Right now, if you’re only capturing basic error messages, you might be missing the details that could explain the issue—things like the exact SQL error codes or more specific timeout information. Capturing the full exception stack, including inner exceptions, is critical.
You might want to consider implementing retry logic using EnableRetryOnFailure in your Entity Framework setup. This won't solve the root cause, but it can help mitigate the impact of these transient issues without introducing more manual error handling.
